# If statements in the methods or in the main?

Tags: java

Hi Currently I am on chapter 5 in my book and we studied `if` statements, and `.equals`, and some other basic things. I noticed that in all  of my problems
and in the examples in the book we usually tend to put `if` statements inside those methods within a class. Here is an exercise I did which isn't completely
finished but the picture is clear. I just ask the user to convert between some units. However when I was thinking on how to approach this problem, I didn't want to use if statements in my methods since I wanted the if statements to be about user input, and from my knowledge we should always put the `Scanner` in the main(well this is what we have been doing all the time so far). And because I wouldn't be able to access those scanners from the main I used `if` statements in the main.

Is this bad practise, or is it generally just better to do whatever given the situation? I can see the main getting ugly, in large programs if we put too many
things in there. I only coded one test case below, but you can see how ugly it would get if I did the other combinations.

Heres my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Conversion{
    public double mmToCm(double value){
        value = value / 10.0;
        return value;
    }
    public double cmToMm(double value){
        value = value * 10.0;
        return value;
    }
    public double cmToMeter(double value){
        value = value / 100.0;
        return value;
    }
    public double meterToCm(double value){
        value = value * 100.0;
        return value;
    }
    public double mmToMeter(double value){
        value = value / 1000.0;
        return value;
    }
    public double meterToMM(double value){
        value = value * (1000.0);
        return value;
    }   
}


public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Conversion convertThisVal = new Conversion();
        Scanner typeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner typeTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner valueOne = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Convert From: ");
        String newTypeOne = typeOne.next();
        System.out.println("To: ");
        String newTypeTwo = typeTwo.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the values!");
        double newValueOne = valueOne.nextDouble();

        if (newTypeOne.equalsIgnoreCase("mm") && newTypeTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("cm"))
        {
            System.out.println("cm:" + convertThisVal.mmToCm(newValueOne));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may fit better at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're correct that it won't scale nicely if you have dozens of type checks in the `main()` method.  Instead, a better approach would be to have a util method, or even a class, which can do these checks.  This could be called from `main()`.

Comment: Also note that you can basically work with one converter method only as basically the factor/divisor is a power of 10. So you could just bring your units of measurement in an ordered list, derive the power from that one. Just an idea to avoid many of your ifs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to create a good structured application which is build using separated components and by separated i mean logically not physically, you need to think of each component as an independent party, which means, the conversion logic should be separated from the input logic (by input i mean getting input data)

let's talk about input data a little bit, it could be from `Scanner` as in your case, and it could be from a database, and it could be from a web-request parameters. that lead us to think about conversion logic as separated unit, that takes some parameters (IN) regardless of the source of these parameters, and based on specific logic (some if statements, some other logic) it returns a specific output that will be used later in the process

your conversion class may contain a method that will decide which other conversion method to call based on input parameters.

ex:add this method to your Conversion class

```
public double convert(String newTypeOne, String newTypeTwo, double newValueOne){
    if (newTypeOne.equalsIgnoreCase("mm") && newTypeTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("cm")){
        return mmToCm(newValueOne);
    }else if (...){
        return ...;
    }
    :
    : ... and so on
}
```

as you can see, we made this method to decide which conversion to do based on parameters, which originally obtained using `Scanner` from user.

so your `main` will look like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Conversion convertThisVal = new Conversion();
    Scanner typeOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner typeTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner valueOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Convert From: ");
    String newTypeOne = typeOne.next();
    System.out.println("To: ");
    String newTypeTwo = typeTwo.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the values!");
    double newValueOne = valueOne.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("cm:" + convertThisVal.convert(newTypeOne,newTypeTwo, newValueOne ));
}
```

all new conversion types will be added in `convert()` keeping the caller method unaware or involved in any logic needed to convert the values.

just pass whatever parameters you need to the destination method and let it decide what to do.

this way you will have a conversion component that can be used in any other system, as i told you earlier, (for database, a webservice, ...etc)

hope this helps you.

Comment: Why Didnt I think of this? This is nice and clean and simple. +1

Comment: +1 for nice and neat solution, i think it might be worth to change if statements to switch statements, so code would look more readable

Comment: @user902383 yes, but for questions related to educational i prefer to stick to the original content, as some cases they are forced to use what they learned so far, they can't use other stuff they did not covered yet. i leave it to the OP to do any enhancements ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't use if statement at all.

Create `Converter` interface,

```
interface Converter {
double convert(double value);
}
```

then create multiple implementations of this interface for each conversion you need
in example

```
class MmToCmConverter implements Converter{
    double convert(double value){
    return value / 10.0;
    }
}
```

then create and populate lookup table for converterters

```
Map<String,Converter> lookup = new Hashap<>();
lookup.put("MM2CM",new MmToCmConverter());
```

then to convert your data, all what you need to do is:

```
String code = newTypeOne +"2"+newTypeTwo; //create code
Converter converter = lookup.get(code.toUpper());
double convertedValue = converter.convert(newValueOne);
```

Comment: I dont know what interfaces or maps are yet, I'll keep this in mind for later chapters

Comment: You right, this might be good solution, but it's force you to speed pace of your learning. In this case go with @Yazan solution as it's what you need.